# How to escape string while matching pattern in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, go, sql-like

I want to find rows where a text column begins with a user given string, e.g. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'rob%'` but "rob" is unvalidated user input. If the user writes a string containing a special pattern character like "rob_", it will match both "robert42" and "rob_the_man". I need to be sure that the string is matched literally, how would I do that? Do I need to handle the escaping on an application level or is it a more beautiful way?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 and [go-pgsql](https://github.com/lxn/go-pgsql) for Go.

Answer (score 8):

The _ and % characters have to be quoted to be matched literally in a LIKE statement, there's no way around it. The choice is about doing it client-side, or server-side (typically by using the SQL replace(), see below). Also to get it 100% right in the general case, there are a few things to consider.

By default, the quote character to use before _ or % is the backslash (\), but it can be changed with an ESCAPE clause immediately following the LIKE clause.
In any case, the quote character has to be repeated twice in the pattern to be matched literally as one character.

Example: `... WHERE field like 'john^%node1^^node2.uucp@%' ESCAPE '^'` would match *john%node1^node2.uccp@* followed by anything.

There's a problem with the default choice of backslash: it's already used for other purposes when [standard_conforming_strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) is OFF (PG 9.1 has it ON by default, but previous versions being still in wide use, this is a point to consider).

Also if the quoting for LIKE wildcard is done client-side in a user input injection scenario, it comes **in addition to** to the normal string-quoting already necessary on  user input.

A glance at a go-pgsql example tells that it uses $N-style placeholders for variables... So here's an attempt to write it in a somehow generic way: it works with standard_conforming_strings both ON or OFF, uses server-side replacement of [%_], an alternative quote character, quoting of the quote character, and avoids sql injection:

```
   db.Query("SELECT * from USERS where name like replace(replace(replace($1,'^','^^'),'%','^%'),'_','^_') ||'%' ESCAPE '^'",
     variable_user_input);
```

Answer (score 4):

To escape the underscore and the percent to be used in a pattern in `like` expressions use the escape character:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE replace(replace(user_input, '_', '\\_'), '%', '\\%');
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing it in a similar way (see my answer)

Comment: I think it doesn't handle the case where \ appears in the user input. I've submitted another answer which I hope covers all.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell the only special characters with the LIKE operator is percent and underscore, and these can easily be escaped manually using backslash. It's not very beautiful but it works.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE
regexp_replace('rob', '(%|_)', '\\\1', 'g') || '%';
```

I find it strange that there is no such functions shipped with PostgreSQL. Who wants their users to write their own patterns?

Comment: I don't remember the issue being discussed on the PostgreSQL mailing lists -- it's possible that it just hasn't come up before.  I suspect that anyone submitting a patch would be well-advised to provide a corresponding function for escaping data to be plugged in to a regular expression, since those seem to be more popular than LIKE among PostgreSQL users (with ~ being the operator for a regular expression match).  If you want to submit a patch, I would be happy to help you with the process and provide review.

Comment: Two or three `replace()` calls are usually much faster than a single `regexp_replace()` call. You should go with Daniel's the very well thought-out answer.

Comment: If you're going this route, you should also escape the `'\'` since the input string could be something like `'rob\%'`, so if you replace `'%'` with `'\%'`, you'll end up with `'rob\\%'`, which is exact/literal `'rob\'` then`'%'` wildcard

Answer (score -2):

The best answer is that you shouldn't be interpolating user input into your sql at all. Even escaping the sql is still dangerous.

The following which uses go's db/sql library illustrates a much safer way. Substitute the Prepare and Exec calls with whatever your go postgresql library's equivalents are.

```
// The question mark tells the database server that we will provide
// the LIKE parameter later in the Exec call
sql := "SELECT * FROM users where name LIKE ?"
// no need to escape since this won't be interpolated into the sql string.
value := "%" + user_input
// prepare the completely safe sql string.
stmt, err := db.Prepare(sql)
// Now execute that sql with the values for every occurence of the question mark.
result, err := stmt.Exec(value)
```

The benefits of this are that user input can safely be used without fear of it injecting sql into the statements you run. You also get the benefit of reusing the prepared sql for multiple queries which can be more efficient in certain cases.

Comment: This solution doesn't let users correctly search for values that contain literal "%" or "_" characters. For example, if user_input equals "100% better", it will erroneously match strings like "100 times better".