# PostgreSQL - How to use wildcard in string condition

Tags: postgresql, wildcard, sql-like

I have a string: A%A

I want to find all string same start with A%A in database.

Example:

```
AABCD - false
AABCE - false
AA%BC - true
```

I use the sql statement:

```
Select * from Tabel where Column like 'AA%B%'
```

But the result are:

```
AABCD
AABCE
AA%BC
```

Because the string include wildcard '%' and postgres select wrong.

Please suggest me a solution

Comment: Check this [how-to-escape-string-while-matching-pattern-in-postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153440/how-to-escape-string-while-matching-pattern-in-postgresql) if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To escape the `%` char, use `\` like this `\%`

**UPDATE**

[Another approach](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) can be achieved by using the `ESCAPE` keyword with empty string after it, this way you tell postgres to disable escaping, and the `%` becomes a normal char

```
select * from Table where Column like '%' ESCAPE '';
```