# How to create StartsWith function for char(n) type with ending space

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

I need to create startswith function which returns true if  char(n) database 
column starts with some characters which
may can contain space at end.
Spaces should treated like other characters.

Database has two values  ´A´ and ´AA´ .  I want that startwith('A') (without trailing space)  matches with both AA and A but   startwith('A ') (with trailing space) matches only with A.

Using sample data below

```
startswith( test, 'A')   -- works
startswith( test, 'A  ')  -- returns wrong result : false
StartsWith(test, rpad('A',20) )  -- returns wrong result : false
```

should return true

but

`startswith( test, RPAD( 'A', 21))`

should return false  since there is extra space in end of check string.

Database contains test column which has char(20) type column and this cannot 
changed.

I tried code below but it returns false.

How to fix this so that it returns true?
Using Postgres starting from 9.1

Andrus.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION public.likeescape( str text )
--  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153440/how-to-escape-string-while-matching-pattern-in-postgresql
RETURNS text AS $$
SELECT replace(replace(replace($1,'^','^^'),'%','^%'),'_','^_') ;
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE or replace FUNCTION public.StartWith( cstr text, algusosa text )
RETURNS bool AS $$
SELECT $2 is null or $1 like likeescape($2) ||'%' ESCAPE '^' ;
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

create temp table test ( test char(20) ) on commit drop;
insert into test values ('A' );
insert into test values ('AA' );

select StartWith(test, 'A ' ) from test
```

I also posted this to pgsql-general mailing list.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the first 3 examples. Given `test` = 'A', `test` starts with 'A', doesn't start with 'A ', and doesn't start with 'A      ...'. Why is that not correct?

Comment: char(20) is padded with trasiling spaces. So `A ` must match. Database has two values  ´A´ and ´AA´ .  I want that startwith('A')  returns both AA and A but   startwith('A ') returns only A. I updated question

Comment: That's incorrect. `CREATE TEMP TABLE t (txt CHAR(20));
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('A');
SELECT '_' || txt || '_' FROM t;` returns `_A_`, and `SELECT LENGTH(txt) FROM t;` returns `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [8.3. Character Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html):

> Values of type `character` are physically padded with spaces to the specified width *n*, and are stored and displayed that way. However, the padding spaces are treated as semantically insignificant. Trailing spaces are disregarded when comparing two values of type `character`, and they will be removed when converting a `character` value to one of the other string types. Note that trailing spaces are semantically significant in `character varying` and `text` values, and when using pattern matching, e.g. `LIKE`, regular expressions.

Note, both your function's arguments are `text`. When you pass it the column `test` and the literal `'A '`, `test` loses the trailing spaces upon the implicit cast whereas the literal doesn't. In your function you'll end up with something like

```
'A' LIKE 'A %' ESCAPE '^'
```

which isn't true.

You can overload your function and create a copy of it, where the first argument is `char` or simply use regular expressions instead of defining your own function, like `test ~ '^A '` or `rtrim()` the spaces off the `char` and treat it like being "spaceless" like `rtrim(test) LIKE 'A%'`. I'd prefer one of the latter.

Comment: Is it possible to create `StartsWith` function which does not remove spaces when char(n) is passed to it as first argument.  n may be different for different queries. I tried  `StartsWith ( cstr char(n), StartOfCstrMayContainSpacesAtEnd text )` but this is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @Andrus: Just use `char` without the `(n)`.